# Scala, Akka, Spray: How to validate json data before processing?

Tags: json, validation, scala, akka, spray-json

I can process this json when all the inputs are valid, i.e with valid keys (including case) and values. The next step is to validate keys and return 400 (Bad Request) if the keys or values are invalid. What is a good way to add this validation?

The API call

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/adsession
Content-Type: application/json
body {
  "sessionId": "abcd123123123",
  "serviceGroup": "1234",
  "targetCode": {"zipcodes":"30096,30188","code2":"value2"}
}
```

Route handler

```
class AdSessionRoutes(services: Services)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, log: LoggingContext) extends ApiRoute(services) {

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)

  val postSession = pathPrefix("adsession") & pathEnd & post

  val route: Route = {
    withService("adSession") { service =>

      postSession {
        entity(as[AdSession]) { adSession =>
          log.info(s"Processing POST ${adSession}")
          val future = (service ? CreateAdSession(adSession)).mapTo[AdSession]

          onComplete(future) {
            case Success(result) =>
              complete(StatusCodes.Created, result)

            case Failure(e) =>
              log.error(s"Error: ${e.toString}")
              complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, Message(ApiMessages.UnknownException))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Model object

```
case class AdSession(
  sessionId: String,
  serviceGroup: String,
  targetCodes: Map[String,String],
  id: Option[String] = None)

object AdSessionJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val adSessionFormat = jsonFormat4(AdSession)
}
```

entity(as[AdSession]) does map keys to case class fields, but I'm not sure how to catch those errors. I would like to capture those errors as well as add additional validations and return 400 with valid json error response.

Answer (score 3):

I know this may be a little late but since akka-http-2.4.6, you can put the verification logic inside a case class. Check out [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/case-class-extraction.html) for info on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Define your own `read` and `write` methods for `AdSession` like this:

```
object AdSessionJsonProtocol {
    implicit object adSessionJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[AdSession] {
        override def read(json: JsValue): AdSession = ???
        override def write(obj: AdSession): JsValue = ???
    }
}
```

Inside `read` function you can perform additional validation.

Another question is how to pass collected errors to Spray route. I would like to suggest you to wrap `AdSession` into `Either[String, AdSession]`, for example:

```
postSession {
        entity(as[Either[String, AdSession]]) { adSession =>
```

So, now your `adSessionJsonFormat` will looks like:

```
implicit object adSessionJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Either[String, AdSession]] {

    override def read(json: JsValue): Either[String, AdSession] = {
      // json.asJsObject.fields access fields, perform checks
      // if everything is OK return Right(AdSession(...))
      // otherwise return Lift("Error Message")
    }

    override def write(obj: Either[String, AdSession]): JsValue = ???
}
```

But, I think it's possible to solve it in more elegant way using some implicit magic.

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a try. Since this is such a common thing (validating input data) I was hoping there must be some good patterns/conventions/examples out there that I can take advantage of. Thanks for pointing out to Scala.Either, didn't know it existed. I can see how I can use Either[AdSession, BadRequestErrors] to achieve what I need to. As small correction though, you probably meant Left instead of Lift.